# Play sound backwards in Corona SDK

Tags: audio, lua, sdk, coronasdk

I am trying to make a voice recorder that plays the sound backwards with Corona SDK. It seems to be possible with Xcode, so is there a solution for Corona as well?

I tried to use a function that plays small bits from the end to the beginning, it sounds quite backwards, but when I make the duration less than 20, it can’t handle it any more.

```
function playBackwards()
    moment = moment-20
    if moment > 0 then
        audio.seek(moment, playbackSoundHandle)
        audio.play(playbackSoundHandle, {duration = 20, onComplete=playBackwards})
    else
        onCompleteSound()
    end
end
```

Comment: Hi there, have you managed to get anything better than this "play by 20ms pieces" or that was the final solution you have used?

Answer (score 0):

The Duration time unit is milliseconds, and 20 milliseconds is really short time, I think you want set the time as 20 seconds, and that means 20,000 milliseconds.

Comment: 20 milliseconds are right, but this is of course not a great solution, the plan was to play the 20-millisecond-pieces forward, but in reverse order, so it appears to be backwards.
I can’t probably make the pieces smaller because it handles only one sound-piece per frame, so I am looking for a better solution than the 20-milliseconds-method.